# Why is my font not working in form text field?

Tags: html, css, forms, fonts, field

I'm trying to add a vag font inside my form. i placed the "VAG Rounded Std-Black.otf" font in a folder outside name "fonts" to link it. but i still cant get it to work in a form text field?

any help to the solution would be helpful. thx yummi

```css
<style type="text/css" href="/fonts">
    
   @font-face {
   font-family: vag;
   src: url(fonts/VAG Rounded Std-Black.otf);
}   
    body {
    background-color: dimgrey;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 50px;
}   
    /*... input message ...*/
    
    input[type=text] {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 37px;
    font-family: vag;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<!-- input message -->
<form><input style="color:white;font-family: vag;" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Type Your Message" onFocus="this.value=''"></form>
```

Comment: Perhaps press F12 and look in the network tab to see if it is even found. I recommend to not have spaces in file names

Comment: Your style tag is not correct. it is a LINK tag that has a href

Answer (score -1):

**You can check This Code**

[**I've Used Google fonts**](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/M+PLUS+Rounded+1c?query=round&sidebar.open=true&selection.family=M%20PLUS%20Rounded%201c:wght@700)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=M+PLUS+Rounded+1c:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form><input style="color:black; font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Type Your Message" onFocus="this.value=''"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using a third party service to load a **completely different font** doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: but There is no inbuilt font family like vag in css. and I've used that fonts just to show you

Comment: That's why they are using `@font-face`!

Comment: thx for all the suggestions, so i guess its NOT possible to link/use a custom font in my page?

Comment: NO!! It is possible ,but I believe that the url is not reachable

Comment: @Yummi — It's entirely possible, but there isn't enough information in your question to determine why it is failing. mplungjan made a couple of suggestions in the comments on the question as to where you should start debugging. You don't seem to have done that yet.

Comment: @Yummi — You've marked this answer as the solution to your problem. Why? This answer is telling you to use a different font and third party hosting of it. Your comment says that the solution was to remove the spaces from the URL.